# new empty line in cmd

Tags: cmd

When I open cmd, the default value is::
**C:>Users\otariki>**

When I press ENTER on keyboard, one new line is written 
**C:>Users\otariki>**

In new line, I do not need the **C:>Users\otariki> string**. I need an empty line. Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: @MarsRover, result also **C:>Users\otariki>** In new line

Comment: Can't get what you want to reach finally? is `echo.` ok? Or you want to continue print in new line?

Comment: @loler I need type in cmd this command: "**D:\x\xampp\apache\bin>ab -c 10000 localhost/cult/hotelguide.ge/oto_test**"

Comment: Type `cd /d D:\x\xampp\apache\bin` followed by `ENTER` followed by `ab -c 10000 localhost/cult/hotelguide.ge/oto_test` followed by `ENTER`.

Comment: @OTARIKI at first ensure your `xampp` directory. then do: `d:`, then cd `x\xampp\apache\bin`, then `ab -c 10000 localhost/cult/hotelguide.ge/oto_test`

Answer (score 1):

This is the "PROMPT" variable, you cant set it to nothing when its nothing it defaults to the one you had.. nearest you can have is a space.. but.. prompts are useful, indicates the command finished and isnt just waiting, as well as normally tells you where you are.

Comment: that is, I need type in cmd this command:
"**D:\x\xampp\apache\bin>ab -c 10000 http://localhost/cult/hotelguide.ge/oto_test**"
tell please, how?

Comment: just type it in rather than press enter.

Comment: @BugFinder I asked if directory was right and he said that it is. sorry.

Comment: What happens when you just type the command in you want to run.. If it helps do Set prompt=Ready>

Comment: @BugFinder problem is solved, thanks and sorry for unknown language :)

Comment: The same should have been true if you typed what you had shown us... unless the localhost part was relative to that area..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PROMPT $H` to get the appearance of what you want.

Each line will be empty, starting in the 1st position.

But in reality each line will start with `<backspace><space><backspace>`

Answer (score 0):

You can type

```
echo off
```

into the CMD window, so it will not prompt you at all but you can still type in commands.